# Equally distribute a list in python

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have the following list in python:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
```

How do I distribute the list like this:

```
['a','f']
['b','g']
['c','h']
['d','i']
['e','j']
```

And how do I achieve this if I have a list of unequal length and putting the 'superfluous' items into a separate list?

I want to be able to distribute the elements of the original list into **n** parts in the indicated manner.

So if n=3 that would be:

```
['a','d','g']
['b','e','h']
['c','f','i']
```

and the 'superfluous' element in a separate list

```
['j']
```

Comment: @Victory Though it sounds similar, it is not. Check the expected output once.

Comment: Are you trying to keep the output list size fixed at `2` or trying to keep the number of lists fixed at `5`? Also, if you can provide an example of with *superfluous* items and desired output, that would help clarify the question.

Comment: The latter thing. So I am looking for a function that distributes the list __a__ into n lists in the way I indicated. See my edit of the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) with a list comprehension:

```
def distribute(seq):
    n = len(seq)//2  #Will work in both Python 2 and 3
    return [list(x) for x in zip(seq[:n], seq[n:])]

print distribute(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'])
#[['a', 'f'], ['b', 'g'], ['c', 'h'], ['d', 'i'], ['e', 'j']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exceedingly elegant, but here goes:

```
In [5]: a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']

In [6]: [[a[i], a[len(a)//2+i]] for i in range(len(a)//2)]
Out[6]: [['a', 'f'], ['b', 'g'], ['c', 'h'], ['d', 'i'], ['e', 'j']]
```

If you're happy with a list of tuples, you could use `zip()`:

```
In [7]: zip(a[:len(a)//2], a[len(a)//2:])
Out[7]: [('a', 'f'), ('b', 'g'), ('c', 'h'), ('d', 'i'), ('e', 'j')]
```

To convert this into a list of lists:

```
In [8]: map(list, zip(a[:len(a)//2], a[len(a)//2:]))
Out[8]: [['a', 'f'], ['b', 'g'], ['c', 'h'], ['d', 'i'], ['e', 'j']]
```