# split list to 3 parts

Tags: python, django-templates

I have objects list:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

i find some snippet.. http://herself.movielady.net/2008/07/16/split-list-to-columns-django-template-tag/

but they split like this:

```
[1, 2] [3, 4] [5, 6]
```

i need split list like this:

```
l1 = [1, 4]
l2 = [2, 5]
l3 = [3, 6]
```

Please, help build right templatetag.

Comment: What have you tried before asking? Did you try to change the snippet to get what you want?

Comment: In that linked question, many answers will show you how to do it the way you don’t want to, but there are some, for example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python/21767522#21767522) which will give you your desired output.

Comment: Is this question about splitting the list (try `[[l[k] for k in range(i, len(l), N)] for i in range(N)]`) or about building the Django template?

Comment: Also: [Equally distribute a list in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905030/equally-distribute-a-list-in-python)

Comment: tobias_k i mean build Django templates..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1433392/maxime-lorant of course i try.. but have errors, maybe i not good understand how templatetags works

Answer (score 1):

You could gather your lists `l1`, `l2` `l3` in another list using a list comprehension, and afterwards do something to them. For example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
x = [[l[i]] + [l[i+3]] for i in range(len(l) - 3)]
for a in x:
    print(a)
```

will get you

```
[1, 4]
[2, 5]
[3, 6]
```

If you know x contains three lists, you can assign `l1`, `l2`, `l3` with

```
l1, l2, l3 = x
```

Of course, you could just manually assign `l1`, `l2`, `l3` too.

```
l1 = [l[0]] + [l[3]]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h = int(len(l)/2)
l1, l2, l3 = zip( l[:h], l[h:] )
```

`l[:h]` is the first half and `l[h:]` the second half. See [list slices](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

```
>>> l[:h], l[h:]
([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

Then the zip function, see [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

```
>>> zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: It splits the original list in two and zips them together. Clever, but lacks an explanation.

Comment: This is a clever solution for the example problem, but fails for `l == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` assuming that the OP wants to get `[1,4], [2,5], [3,6], [4,7]` for such a list. Also, your `l1, l2, l3` are tuples (which of course could be changed to lists easily).